# The Koi Pond Observation Tower Conundrum

Tags: vacuum, weight

I am building a koi pond. I want to install an observation tower. The observation tower is made of glass, either cuboid,cylindrical or hexagonal. The bottom of the tower sits on a frame which is just below the waterline of the pond the top of the tower will sit 40-60cm above the waterline. The frame is constructed to sit over the side of the pond and is portable so it can be removed over winter/maintenance etc. The observation tower is filled with water by creating a vacuum and allowing the water to fill it.
My question is does the weight of the observation tower increase and therefore is a heavier load on the frame when it is filled with water?
This would be important in terms of frame construction and in particular the force of the frame against the inside of the pond which will be constructed with fibreglass.

https://www.goodshomedesign.com/lookout-glass-tower-for-a-unique-pond-fish/

Comment: Side note: I've been watching videos of these structures in action, and it looks like fish and other creatures get confused and trapped inside. Swimming down to reach open water goes against their instincts. I've heard others say that these structures are notorious for killing frogs and turtles since they get trapped and keep swimming up until they drown.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark H. Wouldn't want anything to get trapped!! I will certainly do some additional research on this!!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Go get a large pitcher and fill it and your sink.  Then pull the pitcher (inverted) up from the sink.  As it clears the surface and is no longer supported by buoyancy, you'll feel the rise in the force you need to support the pitcher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer BowlOfRed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tower will be much heavier when it is filled with water. Basically, you are trying to support a large fish tank.

Comment: Thanks gandalf61

Answer (score 0):

Your frame will have to support both the weight of the plexiglass and the weight of the water above the water line of the pond. Think of it this way: Start with the water tower fully submerged and filled with water. You now have to lift this water out of the pond. Any water out of the pond is no longer supported by buoyancy, so its weight has to be held up by something. This would be your frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fresh water normally weighs 1 kilo per liter, exact weight can depend on temperature, purity, and other factors. So you can easily compute the internal volume of the part of the container that will be above the waterline. To figure the weight you will need to support change liters of volume to kilograms of water, then add the water's weight to the container's weight.